# Finding the volume using Washers

Tags: calculus, integration, solid-of-revolution

Problem:
Find the volume generated when the region bounded by the given curves and line is revolved about
the x-axis.
$$ y = 3x - x^2$$
$$ y = 3x $$
Answer:
Let $V$ be the volume we are trying to find. The first step is to find the points where
$3x - x^2$ and $y = 3x$ intersect.
\begin{align*}
3x - x^2 &= x \\
-x^2 &= 2x \\
x = 0 &\text{ or } x = 2 \\
V &= \int_0^2 \pi \left( (3x - x^2)^2 - x^2 \right) \,\, dx \\
\dfrac{V}{\pi} &= \int_0^2 (3x - x^2)^2 \,\, dx - \int_0^2 x^2 \,\, dx \\
\end{align*}
Now we have two integrals to evaluate.
\begin{align*}
\int_0^2 (3x - x^2)^2 \,\, dx &= \int_0^2 (x^2-3x)^2 \,\, dx \\
\int_0^2 (3x - x^2)^2 \,\, dx &= \int_0^2 x^4 - 6x^2 + 9 \,\, dx \\
\int_0^2 (3x - x^2)^2 \,\, dx &= \dfrac{x^5}{5} - \dfrac{6x^3}{3} + 9x \Big|_0^2 \\
\int_0^2 (3x - x^2)^2 \,\, dx &= \dfrac{32}{5} - \dfrac{6(8)}{3} + 18 \\
\int_0^2 (3x - x^2)^2 \,\, dx &= \dfrac{32}{5} - 16 + 18 \\
\int_0^2 (3x - x^2)^2 \,\, dx &= \dfrac{42}{5} \\
\end{align*}
For the second integral we have:
\begin{align*}
\int_0^2 x^2 \,\, dx &= \dfrac{x^3}{3} \Big|_0^2 = \dfrac{8}{3} \\
\dfrac{V}{\pi} &= \dfrac{42}{5} - \dfrac{8}{3} = \dfrac{ 3(42) - 5(8)}{15} \\
\dfrac{V}{\pi} &= \dfrac{86 }{15 } \\
V &= \dfrac{86\pi}{15}
\end{align*}

However, the book gets: $ \dfrac{ 56 \pi}{15} $.
Where did I go wrong?

Based upon a comment from John Douma, I realized that I copied the question incorrectly. Here is the revised question with my solution which still has the wrong answer.

Problem:
Find the volume generated when the region bounded by the given curses and line is revolved about
the x-axis.
$$ y = 3x - x^2 $$
$$ y = x $$
Answer:
Let $V$ be the volume we are trying to find. The first step is to find the points where
$3x - x^2$ and $y = 3x$ intersect.
\begin{align*}
3x - x^2 &= x \\
-x^2 &= -2x \\
x = 0 &\text{ or } x = 2 \\
V &= \int_0^2 \pi \left( (3x - x^2)^2 - x^2 \right) \,\, dx \\
\dfrac{V}{\pi} &= \int_0^2 (3x - x^2)^2 \,\, dx - \int_0^2 x^2 \,\, dx \\
\end{align*}
Now we have two integrals to evaluate.
\begin{align*}
\int_0^2 (3x - x^2)^2 \,\, dx &= \int_0^2 (x^2-3x)^2 \,\, dx \\
\int_0^2 (3x - x^2)^2 \,\, dx &= \int_0^2 x^4 - 6x^2 + 9 \,\, dx \\
\int_0^2 (3x - x^2)^2 \,\, dx &= \dfrac{x^5}{5} - \dfrac{6x^3}{3} + 9x \Big|_0^2 \\
\int_0^2 (3x - x^2)^2 \,\, dx &= \dfrac{32}{5} - \dfrac{6(8)}{3} + 18 \\
\int_0^2 (3x - x^2)^2 \,\, dx &= \dfrac{32}{5} - 16 + 18 \\
\int_0^2 (3x - x^2)^2 \,\, dx &= \dfrac{42}{5} \\
\end{align*}
For the second integral we have:
\begin{align*}
\int_0^2 x^2 \,\, dx &= \dfrac{x^3}{3} \Big|_0^2 = \dfrac{8}{3} \\
\dfrac{V}{\pi} &= \dfrac{42}{5} - \dfrac{8}{3} = \dfrac{ 3(42) - 5(8)}{15} \\
\dfrac{V}{\pi} &= \dfrac{86 }{15 } \\
V &= \dfrac{86\pi}{15}
\end{align*}

However, the book gets: $ \dfrac{ 56 \pi}{15} $.
Where did I go wrong?

Here is an updated answer based upon the comments from DougM.

Answer:
Let $V$ be the volume we are trying to find. The first step is to find the points where
$3x - x^2$ and $y = x$ intersect.
\begin{align*}
3x - x^2 &= x \\
-x^2 &= -2x \\
x = 0 &\text{ or } x = 2 \\
V &= \int_0^2 \pi \left( (3x - x^2)^2 - x^2 \right) \,\, dx \\
\dfrac{V}{\pi} &= \int_0^2 (3x - x^2)^2 \,\, dx - \int_0^2 x^2 \,\, dx \\
\end{align*}
Now we have two integrals to evaluate.
\begin{align*}
\int_0^2 (3x - x^2)^2 \,\, dx &= \int_0^2 (x^2-3x)^2 \,\, dx \\
\int_0^2 (3x - x^2)^2 \,\, dx &= \int_0^2 x^4 - 6x^3 + 9 \,\, dx \\
\int_0^2 (3x - x^2)^2 \,\, dx &= \dfrac{x^5}{5} - \dfrac{6x^4}{4} + 9x \Big|_0^2 \\
\int_0^2 (3x - x^2)^2 \,\, dx &= \dfrac{32}{5} - \dfrac{6(16)}{4} + 18 \\
\int_0^2 (3x - x^2)^2 \,\, dx &= \dfrac{32}{5} - 24 + 18 \\
\int_0^2 (3x - x^2)^2 \,\, dx &= \dfrac{2}{5} \\
\end{align*}
For the second integral we have:
\begin{align*}
\int_0^2 x^2 \,\, dx &= \dfrac{x^3}{3} \Big|_0^2 = \dfrac{8}{3} \\
\dfrac{V}{\pi} &= \dfrac{2}{5} - \dfrac{8}{3} = \dfrac{ 6 - 24}{15} \\
\dfrac{V}{\pi} &= -\dfrac{18 }{15 } \\
V &= -\dfrac{18\pi}{15}
\end{align*}
This answer is obviously wrong.
The book gets: $ \dfrac{ 56 \pi}{15} $.
Where did I go wrong?

Here is an updated answer based upon the comment from N. F. Taussig. I now have a correct solution.

Answer:

Let $V$ be the volume we are trying to find. The first step is to find the points where
$3x - x^2$ and $y = x$ intersect.
\begin{align*}
3x - x^2 &= x \\
-x^2 &= 2x \\
x = 0 &\text{ or } x = 2 \\
V &= \int_0^2 \pi \left( (3x - x^2)^2 - x^2 \right) \,\, dx \\
\dfrac{V}{\pi} &= \int_0^2 (3x - x^2)^2 \,\, dx - \int_0^2 x^2 \,\, dx \\
\end{align*}
Now we have two integrals to evaluate.
\begin{align*}
\int_0^2 (3x - x^2)^2 \,\, dx &= \int_0^2 (x^2-3x)^2 \,\, dx \\
\int_0^2 (3x - x^2)^2 \,\, dx &= \int_0^2 x^4 - 6x^3 + 9x^2 \,\, dx \\
\int_0^2 (3x - x^2)^2 \,\, dx &= \dfrac{x^5}{5} - \dfrac{6x^4}{4} + \dfrac{9x^3}{3} \Big|_0^2 \\
\int_0^2 (3x - x^2)^2 \,\, dx &= \dfrac{32}{5} - \dfrac{6(16)}{4} + \dfrac{9(8)}{3} \\
\int_0^2 (3x - x^2)^2 \,\, dx &= \dfrac{32}{5} - 24 + 24 \\
\int_0^2 (3x - x^2)^2 \,\, dx &= \dfrac{32}{5} \\
\end{align*}
For the second integral we have:
\begin{align*}
\int_0^2 x^2 \,\, dx &= \dfrac{x^3}{3} \Big|_0^2 = \dfrac{8}{3} \\
\dfrac{V}{\pi} &= \dfrac{32}{5} - \dfrac{8}{3} = \dfrac{ 96 - 40}{15} \\
\dfrac{V}{\pi} &= \dfrac{56 }{15 } \\
V &= \dfrac{56\pi}{15}
\end{align*}
This answer matches that given in the book.

Comment: Why do you have $3x-x^2=x$? Shouldn't that be $3x$?

Comment: @JohnDouma You are right. There is a problem. I did not get the question right. I will update the post.

Comment: You are inconsistent in your curves that bound the region.  You start with $y=3x$, but for most of the work, it looks like you have used $y=x.$  Anyway, $(3x-x^2)^2 = x^4 - 6x^3 + 9x^2$ and I think that is your problem.

Comment: @DougM I believe I am now consistent with $y = x$. I will look at how I evaluate $(3x-x^2)^2$.

Comment: Note that $(3x - x^2)^2 = 9x^2 - 6x^3 + x^4$.  You lost a factor of $x^2$.

Comment: I believe my solution is now correct. If somebody could tell me that as an answer, I can accept the answer and close the question.

Comment: You forgot to change the sign of the volume in the last two terms.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can answer your own question.   You will not be able to accept your answer for $48$ hours, but the important thing is that you were able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With problems like this, it is usually solved by the "Washer Method." This method deals when we have a gap about the rational axis.
[image]

Let's have the red line be $y = 3x - x^2$ and the blue line be $y = x$. Now by looking at the graph we can see that the points of intersection are $0$ and $2$, but we can also find this by some algebra:
$$\text{Let's set the two equations equal to each other: $3x-x^2 = x$}
\\
x^2 = 2x
\\ 
\text{We see $x=0$ is a solution for both sides. To find the other value, let $x\neq0$}
\\
\frac{x^2}{x} = \frac{2x}{x}
\\
x = 2$$
We see that are points of intersection are $0$ and $2$ by the graph and verified by algebra. Now let's look at the Washer Method. This method states:
$$V = \int_a^b \pi [f(x)^2 - g(x)^2]dA$$
Let's think of $f(x)$ as the top and $g(x)$ the bottom of the area we want to calculate. $dA$ is if we are going to integrate with respect to $x$ or $y$. Since we rotation about the $x$-axis we will be integrating with respect to $x$, and the "top" will be $3x-x^2$ and the bottom will be $x$. Now we will perform the integration:
$$V = \int_0^2 \pi[(3x-x^2)^2 - (x)^2]dx
\\
=\pi \int_0 ^2 [(9x^2 - 6x^3 +x^4) - (x^2)]dx
\\
=\pi \int_0 ^ 2 [x^4 -6x^3+8x^2]dx \\ =\pi \big[ \frac{x^5}{5} - \frac{6x^4}{4} + \frac{8x^3}{3}\big] \bigg|_0^2
\\
= \pi \big[ \frac{32}{5} - \frac{48}{2} - \frac{64}{3}\big]
\\ = \boxed{\frac{56 \pi}{15}}$$